# WPF DatePickerTextBox- change font color / opacity when IsEnabled == false

Tags: wpf, datepicker, isenabled

I'm having a hard time trying to style myself out of the problem specified in the title. Has anyone here done that?

When the `DatePicker` control is disabled the font on the `DatePickerTextBox` is gray and hard to read. I'm changing to change that.

Regards, Fredrik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enabled-ness of a `DatePicker` is controlled using a semi-opaque overlay in its control template called `PART_DisabledVisual`.  Your only real option is to re-style the whole `DatePicker` `ControlTemplate` using Expression Blend or ShowMeTheTemplate or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215.aspx) and change these lines:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF"/>
<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Height="18" Width="19" Margin="3,0,3,0" />
```

to this:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Transparent" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1"/>
<Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Transparent" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" Width="19"/>
```

which will stop the overlay from graying out the `TextBox`.  What to do instead when disabled, if anything, is then up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into the [SystemColors class...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) In the resources for a given control, you can override one of those colors by specifying a Brush. For example:

```
<Brush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
```